# How to bind to an objects object attribute in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

Right consider this scenario, I have a report and that report has comments.
Now when I display the report I want to see the comments and add more comments if required.

So hence I have 3 objects

```
MyReport
MyReportComment
MyReportCreateViewModel
```

The first two are there so I can have a report with comments, the third is one created to handle the 2 and so I can create a view.

All's well, but now I want to handle that post - this should suffice.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(Models.MyReportCreateViewModel ViewCreateModel)
```

I want to be sure, I want to bind the comment field (in the MyReportComment) to the one in ViewCreateModel.MyReportComment to avoid overposting.

How would I do that? Normally I would do this.

```
[Bind(Include="Title,Content")] Models.MyReport report
```

If it was a 'simple' view taking one simple object, but I don't see how to do this in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right there is a simple answer here you can't. The correct day of doing this isn't to pass the complex object in at all (even though it can be done!)

Pass the `id` and create the object you want to then use something like this

```
if (TryUpdateModel(instructorToUpdate, "",
               new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "HireDate", "OfficeAssignment" }))
```

Where the LastName, FirstMidName etc are the attribute names of the class you are trying to update.

That will all populate the errors and help out like that.